# What happen if disable tablet support from manifest

Tags: android

I'd like to know, if possible, what happen if I release an update on the Adroid market of my app that disable the possibility to install it on tablet.
The tablets that have already purchased the application will see the update? If yes what will happen to the tablet that will update? They'll be able to redownload the latest version purchased?

Thanks to all.

LB

Answer (score 0):

I don't think people with tablets would be able to redownload the old version -- you would have to de-activate that version so it wouldn't be available for download anymore.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, tablet users will simply not see the app anymore. It *might* still appear under "my apps", but they will certainly not be able to update the app anymore.

People who never downloaded your app will certainly not see it anymore in Market (Play).

It would be bad practice for you to do this. If tablet users paid for your app, you should not leave them hanging like that.

You might want to look into [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html).